# Drawing a bar chart using bin sizes

Tags: r

```
Arrival_Frequency     Total_Arrival
           0-1              2633586
           2-4               223079
           4-7                 5281
           7+                  1718
```

How to get bar plot for this. If use normal `geom_bar()` it gives the count not the total.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

```
library(scales)
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Arrival_Frequency, y=Total_Arrival))+ 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number()) +
  ylab("Total Arrival") + xlab("Arrival Frequency")
```

[image]

Your values are wide apart. So, you can think of transforming the values like

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Arrival_Frequency, y=Total_Arrival))+ 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log", labels = label_number()) +
  ylab("log (Total Arrival)") + xlab("Arrival Frequency")
```

[image]

Comment: `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` is equivalent to `geom_col()`.  If you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data, use `geom_col()` instead.